# Editing run_list of nodes from a recipe and initiating chef-client on other node.

Tags: chef-infra

I have a scenario where a new node is to be added to an existing cluster , this  would require configuration changes to be done at all the existing nodes of the cluster in a specific sequence.

To tackle this can a recipe running on the newly created be made to temporarily change the run-list of the other nodes (found through search mechanism) and initiate chef-client run on them and later revert it back once done.

What can be the best ways to handle such scenarios where change in one node of cluster should trigger changes on the other node.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chef's search feature in your cookbooks to dynamically determine the members of a cluster based on some shared attribute like a role. An example would be the [HA proxy cookbook](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/haproxy/blob/develop/recipes/_discovery.rb#L20):

```
pool_members = search("node", "role:appserver AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}") || []
```

In this scenario you need to "kick-start" the chef client on the load balancing node whenever a new node is added:

```
knife bootstrap new_node ....
knife ssh "role:loadbalancer AND chef_environment:app1" "chef-client"
```